# How can I re-install the Software & Updates app?

Tags: release-freya, system-installation

The "Software & Updates" app is missing from elementary OS 0.3.2, how can I re-install it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must open a terminal and write:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-gtk
```

Comment: OK Done.....Noobs huh ?!

Comment: Yep noobs like myself

Comment: What's the command for fedora?