# Soft lockup and delayed boot

Tags: boot, nvidia

Freshly installed elementary os with nvidia drivers will lock up during the boot, delaying to boot by roughly 30s. Is there anything I can do to stop that? I have blacklisted non-nvidia drivers.

Here is dmesg log:

```
[    2.606370] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    2.606372] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[    2.608601] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    2.611268] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    2.611318] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 246
[    2.611373] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20150116 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[    2.611376] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  361.42  Tue Mar 22 18:10:58 PDT 2016
[    2.638320] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  361.42  Tue Mar 22 17:29:54 PDT 2016
[    2.658866] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver in lite mode, major device number 245
[    2.663479] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    2.684221] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
[    2.736411] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    2.747185] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input19
[    2.747229] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input20
[    2.747280] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input21
[    3.000982] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input22
[    3.001017] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input23
[    3.001046] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input24
[    3.001075] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input25
[    3.099469] EXT4-fs (sdb3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    3.140468] audit: type=1400 audit(1475335951.975:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/ippusbxd" pid=802 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.140964] audit: type=1400 audit(1475335951.975:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=800 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.141477] audit: type=1400 audit(1475335951.975:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=797 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.141480] audit: type=1400 audit(1475335951.975:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=797 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.141482] audit: type=1400 audit(1475335951.975:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=797 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.141484] audit: type=1400 audit(1475335951.975:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=797 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.141638] audit: type=1400 audit(1475335951.975:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=805 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.142066] audit: type=1400 audit(1475335951.975:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=796 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.142070] audit: type=1400 audit(1475335951.975:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=796 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.218169] NVRM: Your system is not currently configured to drive a VGA console
[    3.218173] NVRM: on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver
[    3.218175] NVRM: requires the use of a text-mode VGA console. Use of other console
[    3.218176] NVRM: drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in
[    3.218177] NVRM: corruption and stability problems, and is not supported.
[   28.103395] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#5 stuck for 23s! [nvidia-smi:682]
[   28.103426] Modules linked in: binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi nvidia_uvm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec joydev input_leds snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event serio_raw snd_pcm snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd mei_me shpchp mei lpc_ich soundcore 8250_fintek soc_button_array tpm_infineon mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops psmouse drm ahci libahci r8169 mii video fjes
[   28.103427] CPU: 5 PID: 682 Comm: nvidia-smi Tainted: P           OE   4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu
[   28.103428] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B85M-D3H/B85M-D3H, BIOS F3 05/02/2013
[   28.103428] task: ffff88042443a940 ti: ffff8804294dc000 task.ti: ffff8804294dc000
[   28.103501] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc0605c7c>]  [<ffffffffc0605c7c>] os_io_read_dword+0xc/0x10 [nvidia]
[   28.103502] RSP: 0018:ffff8804294dfbf0  EFLAGS: 00000202
[   28.103502] RAX: 00000000e0bdf260 RBX: ffff880429612fa8 RCX: 0000000000000001
[   28.103502] RDX: 000000000000e00c RSI: 00000000000a0000 RDI: 000000000000e00c
[   28.103502] RBP: ffff8804294dfbf0 R08: 00000000000c4835 R09: 00000000000c4835
[   28.103503] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffffffffc0b30a60 R12: 000000000000c000
[   28.103503] R13: 0000000000001a7c R14: ffff880429612fac R15: ffff880429612fb0
[   28.103504] FS:  00007f1fd48bd700(0000) GS:ffff88043e340000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[   28.103504] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[   28.103504] CR2: 00007ffdbabc7ff8 CR3: 0000000428993000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
[   28.103505] Stack:
[   28.103506]  ffff880429612f60 ffffffffc0b3a3aa 000000000000c000 ffffffffc0b31175
[   28.103507]  ffff880429612fa8 ffffffffc0b30f54 ffff880429710008 0000000000004f02
[   28.103507]  ffff880429612fac 0000000000000000 ffff880429612fb4 ffffffffc0b1a7ec
[   28.103508] Call Trace:
[   28.103569]  [<ffffffffc0b3a3aa>] _nv018125rm+0x84da/0xbd60 [nvidia]
[   28.103627]  [<ffffffffc0b31175>] ? _nv000859rm+0x85/0xb0 [nvidia]
[   28.103684]  [<ffffffffc0b30f54>] ? _nv013637rm+0x164/0x220 [nvidia]
[   28.103741]  [<ffffffffc0b1a7ec>] ? _nv014136rm+0x7c/0x170 [nvidia]
[   28.103796]  [<ffffffffc0b1eb65>] ? _nv000755rm+0x2d5/0x370 [nvidia]
[   28.103852]  [<ffffffffc0b1ee23>] ? _nv000679rm+0x223/0x3b0 [nvidia]
[   28.103906]  [<ffffffffc0b2c94a>] ? _nv000691rm+0x2ba/0x340 [nvidia]
[   28.103961]  [<ffffffffc0b20a1a>] ? rm_disable_adapter+0x6a/0x130 [nvidia]
[   28.103962]  [<ffffffff810ca100>] ? up+0x10/0x50
[   28.103993]  [<ffffffffc0609273>] ? nv_uvm_notify_stop_device+0x63/0x80 [nvidia]
[   28.104022]  [<ffffffffc05fa73d>] ? nv_close_device+0xed/0x130 [nvidia]
[   28.104050]  [<ffffffffc05fc940>] ? nvidia_close+0xd0/0x300 [nvidia]
[   28.104078]  [<ffffffffc05fa39c>] ? nvidia_frontend_close+0x2c/0x50 [nvidia]
[   28.104080]  [<ffffffff8120f544>] ? __fput+0xe4/0x220
[   28.104081]  [<ffffffff8120f6be>] ? ____fput+0xe/0x10
[   28.104083]  [<ffffffff8109ecf1>] ? task_work_run+0x81/0xa0
[   28.104084]  [<ffffffff81003242>] ? exit_to_usermode_loop+0xc2/0xd0
[   28.104085]  [<ffffffff81003c6e>] ? syscall_return_slowpath+0x4e/0x60
[   28.104087]  [<ffffffff81830850>] ? int_ret_from_sys_call+0x25/0x8f
[   28.104095] Code: 1f 44 00 00 55 89 fa 48 89 e5 ec 5d c3 66 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 89 fa 48 89 e5 66 ed 5d c3 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 89 fa 48 89 e5 ed <5d> c3 66 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 85 ff 48 89 e5 75 10 85 d2 48
```

Comment: did you installed some additional apps? The delay is before login screen or after login?

Comment: before login screen and some, but it is related to nvidia driver, if I remove it and change back to open source, it works without lockup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem for the past few days. The problem seems to be with the `nvidia-smi` tool that ships with NVIDIA drivers. I tried multiple driver versions, but the same problem arises.

I did a little reading and it seems that `nvidia-smi` is not compatible with a lot of lower spec'd GeForce graphics cards anyway, so you can disable it and the problem goes away.

**If you comment out this line:**

`ACTION=="add" DEVPATH=="/module/nvidia" SUBSYSTEM=="module" RUN+="/usr/bin/nvidia-smi"`

**in this file:**

`/lib/udev/rules.d/*-nvidia.rules`

**The problem goes away.**

Comment: I will check it out when I get back home

Answer (score 0):

First of all, uninstall NVIDIA drivers.

Then, `sudo apt install ubuntu-drivers-common` and open Driver Manager, then select the driver that is detected. They will automatically do the right things to make it work.

Also, bring some info of your computer it it didn't work.

Comment: I already have ubuntu-drivers-common installed. My GPU is GTX 770, nvidia driver is nvidia-361

Comment: Oh, so that's not the issue... Hm... I just want to focus on these lines:
`[3.218169] NVRM: Your system is not currently configured to drive a VGA console
[3.218173] NVRM: on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver
[3.218175] NVRM: requires the use of a text-mode VGA console. Use of other console
[3.218176] NVRM: drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in
[3.218177] NVRM: corruption and stability problems, and is not supported.`

Anyways, I found that graphic has some issues with Linux on Reddit... Have you tried to disable the internal graphics?

Answer (score 0):

Could just be a driver issue—361 is old. Try using [the latest Nvidia drivers](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/8329/5565).

As of today, [Nvidia's website says](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/108586/en-us) that 367.57 is the recommended driver, but I'd just use 370.

> In menus, you can click on "Applications" in the upper-left corner of your screen and type to search for "[Software & Updates](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/4392/5565)". You can install proprietary drivers in its "Additional drivers" tab.
>
> [image: SOftware & updates]
>
> For more control/specificity, install via the command line: ...
>
> ...
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
>      sudo apt-get update
>      sudo apt install nvidia-###
>
> (If you Tab twice after typing "nvidia-" in the above command, Terminal will list all possible packages with that prefix.)

See [the rest of my directions](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/8329/5565) for more depth.

Comment: tried latest drivers, still lockup happens

Comment: It also matters how you install it—did you do it from the package or from `apt`? Was 370 chosen at boot and was the error exactly the same? Have you tried a [manual install](http://askubuntu.com/a/423619/49899)? Also you might find that a kernel upgrade (to 4.8, used in Ubuntu Yakkety) patches the incompatibility