# HDMI completely broken in Loki?

Tags: release-loki, hdmi

I have an Nvidia card. Was using Freya until a few hours ago, installed Loki and now the HDMI is 100% not working. The secondary display (a Hitachi TV) shows no signal at all.

I tried `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` as instructed [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/8330/9), but it did nothing. I installed the Nvidia X Server Settings from the App Center, also nothign.

Drivers available originally:

[image]

After I upgraded the Nvidia drivers to 340.98:

[image]

Info:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -A 3 "VGA"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G96 [GeForce 9500 GT] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. G96 [GeForce 9500 GT]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_340

$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
model    : G96 [GeForce 9500 GT]
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000640sv000019DAsd00006046bc03sc00i00
driver   : nvidia-304 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : nvidia-340 - third-party free recommended

== cpu-microcode.py ==
driver   : amd64-microcode - distro non-free
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Answers are yes and yes. What drivers are you using and what version? ([for the commands](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/8329/5565))

Comment: What did you add to Loki to be able to access the windows you show in your answer?

Comment: It's "Software & Updates" in the Applications menu—forgot to add that

Comment: I have no such entry in the applications menu (Slingshot, right?)

Comment: It won't have an icon but should be searchable. Yep, slingshot.

Comment: No, you must have installed something to get that. I have a brand new Loki and it's not there. The 'Software center' in Freya was replaced in Loki by the 'App Center', and it has no such options.

Comment: Hm, strange. I [do believe](https://itsfoss.com/things-todo-elementary-os-freya/) it's part of the default install, but I'll have a look through the dotdesktop files

Comment: I installed the app from the 'App center'. I also installed `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. Tried a couple of drivers, no changes.

Comment: Was just going to post [this](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/4392/5565) for downloading the app. Can you update your question with the driver are you on now and the drivers you tried? What card(s) are you using? (the command is in my original link) Did you try rebooting in-between?

Comment: I'd post a screenshot but that is *yet another* thing that worked in Freya now broken in Loki. I'll add some more info to the question.

Comment: :) It should work from the app but the keyboard shortcuts are busted. I feel ya

Comment: Can you paste your results from `lspci -k | grep -A 3 "VGA"` and `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`? (to make sure the right driver is active, you might need to disable/remove the other ones)

Comment: @wolf see updated answer (was 2 AM yesterday and I went to bed, sorry)

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to fix this issue following steps given here [Install Nvidia driver instead nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-nouveau).

The issue was that, although the nvidia drivers were correctly installed, the nouveau drivers were still being used, even if the nvidia drivers were selected in 'Software & Updates'/Additional drivers.

Steps I followed:

1. Blacklist the modules. Open the blacklist.conf file.

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```

   add the following modules in the file.

   ```
   blacklist vga16fb
   blacklist nouveau
   blacklist rivafb
   blacklist nvidiafb
   blacklist rivatv
   ```

   Save the file and exit.
2. Update the initramfs disk.

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
3. Reboot